# Displaying the end time of a category in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

How would I go about displaying the "active to" time that you can assign to a category in Magento. Ultimately I plan on using this information to create countdown timers for some short term sales on a client's site - but I cannot figure out what variable to call.

Comment: Try to output `var_dump($category->getAttributes())`, look for the name of the attribute you search for and then try something like `$category->getActiveToDate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Active Date' is actually a custom design date, so you can call it using getCustomDesignTo() on a category object.

in design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml you can just run,

```
echo $_category->getCustomDesignTo();
```

after the $_category has been loaded.